# Does both same mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> Her anger was such that she lost control of herself.

> Her anger was such as to lose control of herself.

Does both same mean? Isn't the second weird?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is correct.

The problem with the second one is that it looks as though it is the anger which is losing control rather than her so it is definitely incorrect.

By the way your title would be better as "Do these two mean the same?" or "Do both of these mean the same?".

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out where I was wrong.